# Java: Generating list of possibilities from the given details

Tags: java, math, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

public class PossibilityGame
{
    private  List<String> list1, list2, list3, list4;

    public PossibilityGame()
    {

        list1 = new ArrayList();
        list1.add("one");
        list1.add("two");
        list1.add("three");
        list1.add("four");

        list2 = new ArrayList();
        list2.add("red");
        list2.add("yellow");
        list2.add("green");
        list2.add("white");

        list3 = new ArrayList();
        list3.add("shirt");
        list3.add("T-Shirt");
        list3.add("denim");
        list3.add("skirt");
        list3.add("short");

        list4 = new ArrayList();
        list4.add("karate");
        list4.add("tennis");
        list4.add("foot ball");
        list4.add("chess");

    }

    void generatePossibilities()
    {
        //Possibility Method Goes here
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("Generating Possibilities");

        PossibilityGame p = new PossibilityGame();
        p.generatePossibilities();

    }
}
```

In here, I have 4 arraylists, each containing 4 Strings. I want to generate the list of possibilities these strings can be printed. For an an example, have a look at the following

One, red, shirt, karate  //Here, "one" is taken from list1, location 1; red is taken from list2, location 1; shirt is take from list3 location 1; karate is taken from list4 location1

one,yellow,T-shirt,tennis //Here, "one" is taken from list1, location 1; yellow is taken from list2, location 2; T-shirt is take from list3 location 2; tennis is taken from list4 location2

I want to generate all the possibilities as above examples. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Smells like homework.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not a homework. I am not a student anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(String s1 : list1)
    for(String s2 : list2)
        for(String s3 : list3)
            for(String s4 : list4)
                System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s %s", s1, s2, s3, s4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use four nested for loops.